# GROUP BY ROLLUP через стандартный GROUP BY

Tags: sql

Всем доброго дня!
Нужно написать запрос через GROUP BY, который выведет тот же результат, что и данный запрос через GROUP BY ROLLUP. Натолкните, пожалуйста, на мысль.
[image: Запрос, который нужно переписать]

Comment: В разных диалектах SQL ROLLUP работает несколько по разному. Какой конкретно диалект используется и какие именно подитоги добавляет этот ROLLUP в вашем диалекте ? А вообще не помешало бы давать текст запроса текстом, а так же примеры таблиц с данными, то же текстом, что бы можно было скопировать, создать БД и пробовать экспериментировать

Comment: Но в общем виде я бы наверное домножил выборку на что то вроде `select 1 as X union all select 2`, каким нибудь case обеспечил разную группировку для записей типа 1 и типа 2 и возможно что нибудь дофильтровал бы в having